# Denormalising relationships with django-import-export

Tags: django, django-import-export

I have room booking application with a Booking model that has a simple ForeignKey relationship to my Room model. Here's a super-brief idea of what I'm dealing with:

```
class Room(..):
    floor = models.IntegerField()
    number = models.IntegerField()
    ...

class Booking(..):
    room = models.ForeignKey('Room')
    ...
```

I've been using django-import-export on the Booking model to let the admin take backups of this data in a way they can import into Excel. It's been really useful for quickly giving them data on demand without costing them my time.

My problem is that the room relationship is ignored; it pumps out the `room_id` instead of following the relationship. I understand how this makes sense for the sake of importing data but for all practical external purposes, the Room's `primary_key` is completely useless. People looking at Booking data need to know which floor and number Room it's for.

Is there a simple way to add extra data to the django-import-export's data to essentially denormalise those fields through?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Getting started](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting_started.html) in documentation.

When defining ModelResource fields it is possible to follow model relationships:

```
class BookResource(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('author__name',)
```

In your case fields would be `('room__floor', 'room__number',)`

Answer (score 0):

It's actually not that painful! We need to override a couple of the `ImportExportModelAdmin` functions on our ModelAdmin to add the extra data to the query, and then pull it through.

```
class BookingAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    ...

    def get_resource_class(self):
        from import_export.fields import Field
        rc = super(BookingAdmin, self).get_resource_class()
        for f in ('room_floor', 'room_number'):
            rc.fields[f] = Field(f, f, readonly=True)
        return rc

    def get_export_queryset(self, request):
        rs = super(BookingAdmin, self).get_export_queryset(request)
        return rs.annotate(
            room_floor=F('room__floor'),
            room_number=F('room__number')
        )
```

No idea what happens on import though. I've set the fields to readonly so they *should* be ignored. Thankfully we're past the point where importing matters.